# many to many order by relantionship

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following tables:

```
+---------+    +-----------+     +---------+
| USER    |    | USER_BOX  |     | BOX     |
| id      |    | user_id   |     | id      |
| name    |    | box_id    |     | name    |
|         |    |           |     |         |
+---------+    +-----------+     +---------+
```

What I want to do is query the DB as to list all boxes, but have all boxes that have relations with an user to be listed first, and **only once**. I'm stuck and I'm not even sure that MySql supports such a query.

```
        USER                    BOX                 USER_BOX
+--------|--------+      +--------|--------+   +--------|--------+
|   0    | Jonh   |      |   0    | Boobox |   |   0    |    4   |
+--------|--------+      |   1    | RedBox |   |   0    |    3   | 
                         |   2    | GGbox  |   +--------|--------+
                         |   3    | OKbox  |   
                         |   4    | boxy   |   
                         +--------|--------+
```

Resulting query should return:

```
4 - boxy
3 - Okbox
0 - Boobox    
1 - RedBox
2 - GGbox
```

Edit: The idea is to be able to query by user, so it's easier to locate users boxes in a large list.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because there seems to be no effort of finding a solution.


Comment: Good point, show what you've tried so far.

Comment: I'm embarrassed to show what I've done, especially since it hasn't worked at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT b.id, b.name
FROM BOX b
LEFT JOIN (
    USER_BOX ub
    JOIN USER u ON (user_id = u.id)
) ON (box_id = b.id)
ORDER BY
    u.id IS NULL,
    b.id DESC
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a4f304/4/0

EDIT: Actually there's no need to join on `USER`.
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a4f304/7/0

Comment: hahh! your solution is better. +1 Pills ;)

Comment: If there is more than one user-box relationship, it will still be printed: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/edda0/1. I'll update the question to emphasize.

Comment: @localhost just use `SELECT DISTINCT`

Comment: Nice! I'm using the first example that joins the user table so I can specify the user id: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d7385/4/0

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
SELECT a.id, a.name
FROM BOX AS a
LEFT JOIN USER_BOX AS b
 ON a.id = b.box_id
ORDER BY CASE WHEN b.box_id IS NOT NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
      ,a.id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM BOX
WHERE box_id IN (SELECT box_id FROM USER_BOX)
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM BOX
WHERE box_id NOT IN (SELECT box_id FROM USER_BOX)
```